# Libgdx: font characters get stacked up on each other

Tags: android, fonts, libgdx

I am simply drawing font with libgdx as :

```
PPM = 16.0f;
game.font.getData().setScale(1/PPM);
game.font.getRegion().getTexture().setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Linear, Texture.TextureFilter.Linear);

game.font.draw(game.batch, "plot4", 0,0);
```

I scaled it down because I am using box2d units for drawing.
String is merging and not showing properly

[Screenshot of android screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUQ0J.png)

Comment: Is `PPM` an `int`? You may want to change that to `1f / PPM` to ensure you're getting a float result. Also, try setting `font.setUseIntegerPositions(false);`.

Comment: no its already set as float PPM = 16.0f

Comment: It worked but what does this method do by the way?

Comment: BitmapFont by default rounds off the X and Y world position of every character to an integer. This is useful when drawing text to the screen at 1:1 pixel scale, because it will look less blurry. By the way, it is not common to use the same camera/viewport for your game world and for your UI. What if your camera has to move around in the world, do you move your UI with it?

Comment: So, does that mean that integer position for every character is calculated instead of whole string?? Yes, I want my UI to move with world camera as it is a dialog of a sprite.

Comment: Yes, every character. So that's why they look stacked together when you scale them down. Ahh, that is one case where it might make sense to do that. I would suggest at least using trilinear filtering for the texture of the font to minimize blurriness and tiny ripple-like effects as it moves around on screen.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Please write your comment as answer so that the question is answered and an upvote will be a great help as well.